# why this is not printing all the things and its only giving total number of words in a file?

Tags: python

Why I am not getting the desired result and only getting the number of words in a file? 
I should also get a list of words without being repeated and also the full content of a file.

```
class text_reader:

# for opening of file
    def __init__(self,file_name):
        global fo
        self.file_name = file_name
        fo=open(file_name,"r")
# for counting no of words in a file
    def wordcount(self):
        num_word=0
        for line in fo:
            words = line.split()
            num_word=num_word + len(words)
        print("Number of words:")
        print(num_word)

# for printing the content of a file   
    def display(self):
        contents = fo.read()
        print(contents)

# for printing list of words in a file and words should not be repeated
    def wordlist(self):
        for x in fo:
            word = x.split()
            list=word.set()
            print(list)



t = text_reader("C:/Users/ALI/Desktop/article.txt")
t.wordcount()
t.display()
t.wordlist()


# article.txt

"""PYTHON IS AN INTERPRETED HIGH-LEVEL PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE FOR GENERAL- 
PURPOSE PROGRAMMING. CREATED BY GUIDO VAN ROSSUM AND FIRST RELEASED IN 1991,
PYTHON HAS A DESIGN PHILOSOPHY THAT EMPHASIZES CODE READABILITY, NOTABLY 
USING SIGNIFICANT """
```

Comment: I don't know, but `list` is a python keyword. Do not use it as a variable name, it'll strike back.

Comment: You can check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644824/python-count-the-total-number-of-words-in-a-file

Comment: Additionally, lists have no method `set()`, but you should use the set operation `set(word)`. Your code should throw an error there...

Comment: I did set(word) but then also I am only getting number of words and rest two I am not getting.

Answer (score 1):

The `fo` object has an internal pointer which points to where the python should start reading the file from. After calling `fo.read()` this now points to the end of the file (i.e. where python finished reading). Thus, subsequent calls to `fo.read()` will now start at the *end* of file, and so return an empty string.

You either need to reset the pointer to the beginning of the file, or call `fo.read()` once in the constructor and save the results.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need global fo. If you explain it, I'll adjust my code.

Here's my version

```
class text_reader():

    # for opening of file
    def __init__(self,file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.content = open(file_name,"r").read()

    # for counting no of words in a file
    def wordcount(self):
        print("Number of words:")
        print(len(self.content.split()))

    # for printing the content of a file   
    def display(self):
        print(self.content)

    # for printing list of words in a file and words should not be repeated
    def wordlist(self):
        for word in set(self.content.split()):
            print(word)


t = text_reader("C:/Users/ALI/Desktop/article.txt")
t.wordcount()
t.display()
t.wordlist()


# article.txt

"""PYTHON IS AN INTERPRETED HIGH-LEVEL PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE FOR GENERAL- 
PURPOSE PROGRAMMING. CREATED BY GUIDO VAN ROSSUM AND FIRST RELEASED IN 1991,
PYTHON HAS A DESIGN PHILOSOPHY THAT EMPHASIZES CODE READABILITY, NOTABLY 
USING SIGNIFICANT """
```